# Apollo-cache-persist Vs a Local Database in Mobile apps

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo-client

In order to persist data in a mobile app, I am struggling to decide between using [apollo-cache-persist](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist) or a local database like `Sqlite`.

Based on [their docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/local-state/), Apollo want their cache to be the single source of truth for all data in a client application:

> Ideally, we would like the Apollo cache to be the single source of
>   truth for all data in our client application.

But could `apollo-cache-persist` totally replace the use of a local database?

---

Aside from persisting data, there is other requirements that I would like to know whether they are supported by `apollo-cache-persist` or not:

1. Is it possible to retrieve data from the cache using complex queries operations like sql joins?

   As an example, let's say that we have 2 objects: Country and State, and we want to retrieve the states of countries whose name begins with the letter 'A'.
   In a relational database, we can use sql joins. But what about retrieving the same data from the cache? is it possible?
2. If there is a breaking schema change, is it possible to keep the old data in the cache?

   In [the github page](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist) the same question is answered by saying that

   > ...it's not possible to migrate or transform your persisted cache data

   and then demonstrating in the code that the old data should be purged.

   Could this be a holdback to not replace a local database with the apollo-cache-persist?

Comment: I am in the same boat as you. Have you tested apollo-cache-persist? Have you decided what to do?

Comment: I couldn't find a satisfying answer to this question, so I ended up using a local database just to be in the safe side, but without disabling totally the Apollo Cache (the memory cache). I would like to give you more details but since I haven't used `apollo-cache-persist` I can't elaborate a fair comparison between the two solutions.

Comment: shot thanks for the feedback. i am going to play around with apollo-cache-persist today and see if i can make it work for me. will post some feedback here if i achieve anything.

Comment: Im sorry ive taken so long to get back to you. but after playing around a bit i realized that it just works strait out of the box.  No need for a local database. You can literally just call the query. if you set your query { fetch-policy : cache-and-network }, it will first read from the cache and then call the network to find changes if there are any. Ive tested this by literately turning my server off and all the data is still loaded exactly as expected without changing anything. so just call the query and if there is no connection to the server(no internet) it just loads the data from cache

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It's good that you get it to work, but were you able to know if `Apollo-cache-persist` has something similar to relational databases as to male complex database queries (like joins for example)? And what about breaking schema changes? Is it really necessary to purge the cache upon changes to the schema?

Comment: apollo-cache-persist just saves the cache in AsyncStorage when you close your app & then loads it again when you open it. No need to refetch anything if there is no changes. not sure i understand correctly, i do my joins on the server and then send the data via graphql so i give my client the data just like im using it, which is cached, so i just have to call the query again even if there is no connection to the server. if you mean purging the cache when making changes to schema after deploy. not to sure about that one, but a condition to call refetch or reset not to difficult. FYI im a noob